# How to get unselected column in typeorm?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I create a user entity with password:

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    userName: string;

    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    email: string;

    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    firstName: string;

    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    lastName: string;

    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false, select: false }) //It is select as false
    password: string;

    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    socket_id: string;

    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    avatar: string;

    @Column({ type: "boolean", default: false, nullable: false })
    is_verify: boolean;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    created_at: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated_at: Date;
}
```

In this `entity`, I set `select` as `false` for `password`. When I find it, don't see the `password` column. How can I find this column?

```js
const user = await this.userRepository.findOneBy({
    email: loginInput.email,
    is_verify: true
})
console.log(user)
```

What things I have to change in this code to get password column?

Answer (score 1):

You can select [hidden column](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/select-query-builder#hidden-columns):

```js
const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({
  where: {
    email: loginInput.email,
    is_verify: true,
  },
  select:{
    password:true,
  },
});
console.log(user);
```

Comment: This will only return you the password, the rest of the fields would be undefined